# Regex - get last part of url and strip .php

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I am a little bit confused with that regex stuff.

Got some links like this:

```
http://www.test.de/mystuff/otherstuff.php

http://www.test.de/mystuff/differentstuff.php

http://www.test.de/mystuff/totallynewstuff.php
```

and I want a redirect that leads to

```
http://www.newsite.de/otherstuff/

http://www.newsite.de/differentstuff/

http://www.newsite.de/totallynewstuff/
```

So far I got this regex

^/(.+?).php?$

and I put this here

```
http://www.newsite.de/$1/
```

that ends in this url

```
http://www.newsite.de/mystuff/otherstuff/
```

Close...but not correct. :/ What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^.*/(.*?)\.php
```

Try this.This will do it.See demo

https://regex101.com/r/pM9yO9/9